# Team Foundation Server, Excel File, Stop publishing and enable refresh

Tags: excel, tfs

Currently i generated excel file from TFS 2013.
I want to disable editing this file for some specific users.

I tried to add these users in the group Reader only, but they can modify the excel file then publish it.

On the other side, i want to give them the ability to refresh the excel file and get the latest status.

Answer (score 0):

By "publish" I assume you mean the Check In permission. Readers don't have an explicit Deny on Check In by default, so you may find that people who can still Check In are members of another group with permissions. The usual group being the Contributors group.

To force the matter you can go to the file in question in Source Control Explorer, right click it and select Advanced -> Security and then explicitly set the Reader group to Deny for the Check In right.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean "publishing work items". If you do then people in the readers group will not be able to publish unless they also have contributed rights. So while they can click "publish" they will not be able to make changes on TFS, and they will be able to refresh.